# out of bounds error when using a list as an index

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have two files: one is a single column (call it pred) and has no headers, the other has two columns: ID and IsClick (it has headers). My goal is to use the column ID as an index to pred.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def LinesInFile(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        for linecount, line in enumerate(f):
            pass
    f.close()
    print 'Found ' + str(linecount) + ' lines' 
    return linecount

path ='/Users/mas/Documents/workspace/Avito/input/'                          # path to testing file
submission = path + 'submission1234.csv' 

lines = LinesInFile(submission)
lines = LinesInFile(path + 'sampleSubmission.csv')


sample = pd.read_csv(path + 'sampleSubmission.csv')
preds = np.array(pd.read_csv(submission, header = None))
index = sample.ID.values - 1
print index
print len(index)
sample['IsClick'] = preds[index]
sample.to_csv('submission.csv', index=False)
```

The output is:

```
Found 7816360 lines
Found 7816361 lines
[       0        4        5 ..., 15961507 15961508 15961511]
7816361
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mas/Documents/workspace/Avito/July3b.py", line 23, in <module>
    sample['IsClick'] = preds[index]
IndexError: index 7816362 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7816361
```

there seems something wrong because my file has 7816361 lines counting the header while my list has an extra element (len of list 7816361)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your csv files to recreate the problem, but the problem looks like it is being caused by your use of `index`.

`index = sample.ID.values - 1` is taking each of your sample ID's and subtracting 1.  These are not index values in `pred` as it is only 7816360 long.  Each of the last 3 items in your index array (based on your print output) would go out of bounds as they are >7816360.  I suspect the error is showing you the first of your `ID-1` that go out of bounds.

Assuming you just want to join the files based on their line number you could do the following:

```
sample=pd.concat((pd.read_csv(path + 'sampleSubmission.csv'),pd.read_csv(submission, header = None).rename(columns={0:'IsClick'})),axis=1)
```

Otherwise you'll need to perform a join or merge on your two dataframes.